# Speed up for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a for loop as follows:

```
import MDAnalysis as mda
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm as tq
import MDAnalysis.analysis.pca as pca
import random

def PCA_projection(pdb,dcd,atomgroup):
    u = mda.Universe(pdb,dcd)
    PSF_pca = pca.PCA(u, select=atomgroup)
    PSF_pca.run(verbose=True)
    n_pcs = np.where(PSF_pca.results.cumulated_variance > 0.95)[0][0]
    atomgroup = u.select_atoms(atomgroup)
    pca_space = PSF_pca.transform(atomgroup, n_components=n_pcs)
    PC1_proj = [pca_space[i][0] for i in range(len(pca_space))]
    PC2_proj = [pca_space[i][1] for i in range(len(pca_space))]
    return PC1_proj, PC2_proj


def Read_bias_potential(bias_potential):
    Bias_potential = pd.read_csv(bias_potential)
    Bias_potential = Bias_potential['En-User']
    Bias_potential = Bias_potential.values.tolist()
    W = [math.exp((-1 * i) / (0.001987*300)) for i in Bias_potential]
    return W

def Bin(PC1_prj, PC2_prj, frame_num, min_br1, max_br1, min_br2, max_br2, bin_num, W):
    #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    data1 = PC1_prj[0:frame_num]
    bins1 = np.linspace(min_br1, max_br1, bin_num)
    bins1 = np.round(bins1,2)
    digitized1 = np.digitize(data1, bins1)
    binc1 = np.arange(min_br1 + (max_br1 - min_br1)/2*bin_num, 
max_br1 + (max_br1 - min_br1)/2*bin_num, (max_br1 - min_br1)/bin_num, dtype = float)
    binc1 = np.around(binc1,3)

    data2 = PC2_prj[0:frame_num]
    bins2 = np.linspace(min_br2, max_br2, bin_num)
    bins2 = np.round(bins2,2)
    digitized2 = np.digitize(data2, bins2)
    binc2 = np.arange(min_br2 + (max_br2 - min_br2)/2*bin_num, max_br2 + (max_br2 - min_br2)/2*bin_num, (max_br2 - min_br2)/bin_num, dtype = float)
    binc2 = np.around(binc2,3)

    w_array = np.zeros((bin_num,bin_num))

    for j in range(frame_num):
        w_array[digitized1[j]][digitized2[j]] += (W[digitized1[j]] + W[digitized2[j]])

    for m in range(bin_num):
        for n in range(bin_num):
            if w_array[m][n] == 0:
                w_array[m][n] = 1e-100

    return w_array, binc1, binc2

def gaussian(Sj1,Slj1,Sj2,Slj2,count):

    sigma1 = 0.5
    sigma2 = 0.5
    Kb = 0.001987204
    T = 300
    h0 = 0.0001
    g = 0
    C1 = 0
    C2 = 0
    for i in range((np.where(Slj2 == Sj2)[0][0] - 5),(np.where(Slj2 == Sj2)[0][0] + 6)):
        if i < 0:
            C2 = i + 1000
        elif i > 999:
            C2 = i - 1000
        else:
            C2 = i

        for j in range((np.where(Slj1 == Sj1)[0][0] - 5),(np.where(Slj2 == Sj2)[0][0] + 6)):
            if j < 0:
                C1 = j + 1000
            elif j > 999:
                C1 = j -1000
            else:
                C1 = j

            g = g + count[C2,C1] * h0 * np.exp( (-(Sj1 - Slj1[C1]) ** 2 / (2 * sigma1 ** 2)) + (-(Sj2 - Slj2[C2]) ** 2 / (2 * sigma2 ** 2)) )

    return np.exp(-g / (Kb * T))

def resampling(binc1, binc2, w_array):
#    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    l =1000
    F = np.zeros((l,l))
    count = np.zeros((l,l))
    Wn = w_array

    for i in tq(range(10000000)):
        SK1 = random.choice(binc1)
        SK2 = random.choice(binc2)
        SL1 = random.choice(binc1)
        SL2 = random.choice(binc2)
        while SK1 == SL1:
            SL1 = random.choice(binc1)
        while SK2 == SL2:
            SL2 = random.choice(binc2)
        F[np.where(binc2 == SK2)[0][0]][np.where(binc1 == SK1)[0][0]] = gaussian(SK1,binc1,SK2,binc2,count)
        F[np.where(binc2 == SK2)[0][0]][np.where(binc1 == SK1)[0][0]] = gaussian(SL1,binc1,SL2,binc2,count)
        W_SK = Wn[np.where(binc2 == SK2)[0][0]][np.where(binc1 == SK1)[0][0]] * F[np.where(binc2 == SK2)[0][0]][np.where(binc1 == SK1)[0][0]]
        W_SL = Wn[np.where(binc2 == SL2)[0][0]][np.where(binc1 == SL1)[0][0]] * F[np.where(binc2 == SL2)[0][0]][np.where(binc1 == SL1)[0][0]]
        if W_SK <= W_SL:
            SK1 = SL1
            SK2 = SL2
        else:
            a = random.random()
            if W_SL/W_SK >= a:
                SK1 = SL1
                SK2 = SL2
            else:
                SK1 = SK1
                SK2 = SK2
    #print('SK =',SK)
        count[np.where(binc2 == SK2)[0][0]][np.where(binc1 == SK1)[0][0]] += 1
    return F
```

where binc1 and binc2 are two np.arrays, gaussian is a gaussian fxn I defined, is there anyway I can speed up this for loop? Now 1000000 steps takes approximately 50 mins. I am thinking about using pytorch but I got no idea on how to do it. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Thanks

I tried to use pytorch, like put all the variables on gpu but it only does worse.

Comment: `binc1` is undefined.  `F` is undefined.  Code needs `import random`. `count` is undefined, `Wn` is undefined...

Comment: It's worth seeing if simply wrapping your functions with [numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/overview.html) gives a decent enough speed-up